# Flex full screen mode

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, fullscreen

I'm new in flex.
I faced problem to make full screen in flex 3.My layout container type like below.

```
<mx:Application >
<mx:Panel>
<mx:ViewStack>

<mx:VBox >
    <mx:VBox >
        <mx:Canvas >
            <mx:HBox width="300" height="300">      

            </mx:HBox>

        </mx:Canvas>
    </mx:VBox>
</mx:VBox>
</mx:ViewStack> 
</mx:Panel>
</mx:Application>
```

the container width and height will be fixed like above.Then when i click a button full screen it will be full screen mode. Please help me with example and tutorial.

best regard.
Mahedi

Comment: you didn't complete your code

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are referring  to full screen as in 'use the whole monitor':

Calling `stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;` will set your flash movie to full screen mode (provided that the `allowFullScreen` parameter has been set to `true` in the object/embed tags of the embedding html page). Scale up the hbox (change its width/height) so that it occupies the whole space available.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.I need more details please.

Comment: sorry for late reply.Actually i need a completed example cause already try to do with some hints but i'm not able to do it. please help me.

Comment: Scale up the hbox (change its width/height) so that it occupies the whole space available.How can i do that please show me with code example.

Answer (score 0):

Just set

```
<mx:HBox width="100%" height="100%">
    //Other Codes
</mx:HBox>
```

Comment: sorry for incomplete code.Firstly,the container width and height will be fixed like below.Then when i click a button full screen it will be full screen mode
<mx:HBox width="300" height="300">
    //Other Codes
</mx:HBox>

Comment: oh.. just put width="100%" height="100%" in <mx:Application>

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand what you want is to change the width / height of the component *at run-time*.

In this case you need to give an id to the HBOx, add a script block, and call the 'width' / 'height' setter on your block.

Is that what you want to do ?

Thanks
PH