# How to use Mac OS X Lion fullscreen abilities in my Flex app?

Tags: macos, actionscript-3, apache-flex, fullscreen

How can I enable the nativ Mac OS X fullscreen feature (incl. the top right button) in my Flex application?

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746725/flex-full-screen-mode) has your answer:

> Assuming you are referring to full screen as in 'use the whole
>   monitor':
>
> Calling stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN; will set
>   your flash movie to full screen mode (provided that the
>   allowFullScreen parameter has been set to true in the object/embed
>   tags of the embedding html page).

If you're building an AIR App; read this article on [using FullScreen functionality](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Using_the_FullScreen_functionality_in_AIR-8004.html).  It also uses the same displayState property.

```
// Enter Fullscreen Interactive State
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
// Enter Standard Fullscreen State
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
// Enter Normal State
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.NORMAL;
```

Comment: I think the Asker wants OS X fullscreen, not Flash fullscreen. In OS X, you can go fullscreen on pretty much any app and it will still give you access to the menubar by pressing the mouse against the top of the screen. For the most part, it is useless. But obviously the Asker has a use for it.

Comment: @Apocalyptic0n3 I'm not clear on what the difference is between Mac Fullscreen and Flash fullscreen.

Comment: It takes a single app fullscreen. It moves the app to a new Space (allowing you to keep moving between apps, even multiple fullscreen apps), blacks out any secondary monitors, and goes fullscreen. While fullscreen, it still allows access to the top menubar and dock as well as Notifications from Growl/Notification Center. Flash fullscreen just goes fullscreen. Renders the dock and menubar unusable.